# ArrayList Assignment

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following code written in my main method:

```
    ArrayList<String> finalPhrases = new ArrayList<String>();
    switch (response){
    //TODO: FIX
        case 2: finalPhrases = modeOne(inputScanner, patternScanner);
        case 1: finalPhrases = modeTwo(inputScanner, patternScanner);
        case 0: finalPhrases = modeThree(inputScanner, patternScanner);
    }   

    System.out.println(finalPhrases);
```

where (response) is a variable that will either be 2,1,0 and modeOne,Two,Three are methods I wrote that return an ArrayList. I'm running into an issue where when I try printing finalPhrases, it shows that the ArrayList is empty, and I'm thinking that this might be something to do with memory referencing.

I know that the methods are working properly because when I run

```
System.out.println(modeOne(inputScanner, patternScanner))
```

it prints out the correct arraylist, but once I assign it, it fails. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Put a 'break;' after each case, otherwise you fall through and process every one after the first. So if response is 2, you call all 3 methods. If response can ever be anything other than 0-2, you should add a default case as well.

Comment: Also, if you could show at least one of your 'modeNumber' methods, that would be helpful.

Comment: The points about break are correct, and important, but if all three methods would be expected to return a non-empty list then it appears that `response` is something other than 0, 1, or 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use break in your case statement.

```
ArrayList<String> finalPhrases = new ArrayList<String>();
switch (response){
//TODO: FIX
    case 2: 
        finalPhrases = modeOne(inputScanner, patternScanner);
        break;
    case 1: 
        finalPhrases = modeTwo(inputScanner, patternScanner);
        break;
    case 0:
        finalPhrases = modeThree(inputScanner, patternScanner);
        break;
    default:
        // TODO add code for value other than 0, 1 or 2
        break;
}   

System.out.println(finalPhrases);
```

I have added the default clause to capture the scenario where response has a value other than 0, 1 or 2.

I suspect response holds a different value to the scenarios you wish to capture so default is important here and you should write code for the TODO.